# YII2 Kartik gridview disable pdf export

Tags: yii2

How to disable the pdf export property in kartik gridview?

I have installed the kartik gridview and it gave me the following error.

> The class '\kartik\mpdf\Pdf' was not found and is required for PDF
> export functionality. To include PDF export, follow the install steps
> below. If you do not need PDF export functionality, do not include
> 'PDF' as a format in the 'export' property. You can otherwise set
> 'export' to false to disable all export functionality.
>
> Please ensure you have installed the 'yii2-mpdf' extension. To
> install, you can run this console command from your application root:
>
> php composer.phar require kartik-v/yii2-mpdf: "@dev"

I do not want to installe the mpdf. Just want to disable it. Where can I edit it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should set `export` property to `false`, it's even mentioned in error text.

```
use kartik\grid\GridView;

...

<?= GridView::widget([
    ...
    'export' => false,
]) ?>
```

Read more in [official docs](http://demos.krajee.com/grid#grid-export).

**Update:**

Another way to do that is exclude PDF format from `exportConfig`.

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'exportConfig' => [
        GridView::CSV => [
            ...
        ],
        ... // Make sure there is no GridView::PDF
    ],
]) ?>
```

Comment: I want to disable only the pdf.... I solved this by commenting the `self::PDF=>... at line 1032` in the `GridView.php` file at the `vendor/kartik-v/yii2-grid/`

Comment: This is not a solution, just a temporary hack. You changes will be lost after next `composer update`. Remember, you should not modify any files under `vendor` folder. And you asked that you don't want to install `mpdf`. Seems like is the only way to prevent installation of this extension.

Comment: `If you do not need PDF export functionality, do not include 'PDF' as a format in the 'export' property` What does this mean? how can it be done?

Comment: Updated the answer with alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using both `kartik\export\ExportMenu` & `kartik\export\GridView`, you have to set `exportConfig` property for 'PDF' to `false` in `ExportMenu` and `export` property to `false` in GridView.

See below:

```
use kartik\grid\ExportMenu;    
use kartik\grid\GridView;

<?= ExportMenu::widget([
    ...
    'exportConfig' => [
        ExportMenu::FORMAT_PDF => false,
    ],
]) ?>

<?= GridView::widget([
    ...
    'export' => false,
]) ?>
```